# How to use "repeat()" css function combined with Angular ngStyle directive?

Tags: html, css, angular, components

Let's assume that you have `div` in some component's html template:

```html
<div [ngStyle]="{'grid-template-columns': repeat(5, 20%)}"></div>
```

How to make `repeat()` css function work in that scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put the right side in quotations:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'grid-template-columns': 'repeat(5, 20%)'}"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this question and thought I'd share how I used it in my code.

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'grid-template-columns': 'repeat(' + buttonData.length + ', 1fr)'}"></div>
```